# ANR keyDispatchingTimedOut Unity

Tags: java, android, multithreading, unity-game-engine

My Unity Android Game is generating an ANR keyDispatchingTimedOut occasionally. I haven't witnessed it myself but I have a report from the Developer Console.

```
DALVIK THREADS:
(mutexes: tll=0 tsl=0 tscl=0 ghl=0)
"main" prio=5 tid=1 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40f834c0 self=0x11ed808
| sysTid=12086 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1074333044
| schedstat=( 101396229 44869695 78 ) utm=8 stm=2 core=1
at com.unity3d.player.NativeLoader.load(Native Method)
at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.a((null):-1)
at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.<init>((null):-1)
at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity.onCreate((null):-1)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4478)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1050)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2061)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2124)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1248)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4645)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

"Thread-932" prio=5 tid=10 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x418d84a8 self=0x1535b88
| sysTid=12100 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=20362336
| schedstat=( 531615 7318385 4 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=1
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Binder Thread #2" prio=5 tid=9 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x418a4690 self=0x14b9598
| sysTid=12098 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=21437456
| schedstat=( 7238385 612384 5 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Binder Thread #1" prio=5 tid=8 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x418a4538 self=0x1548380
| sysTid=12097 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=21599232
| schedstat=( 5762539 628077 9 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"FinalizerWatchdogDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=7 TIMED_WAIT
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x418a0ff0 self=0x14d8600
| sysTid=12096 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=21571632
| schedstat=( 670846 1434538 6 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0
at java.lang.VMThread.sleep(Native Method)
at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:1031)
at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:1013)
at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.run(Daemons.java:213)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"FinalizerDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=6 WAIT
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x418a0e98 self=0x1528680
| sysTid=12095 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=21572056
| schedstat=( 518768 6248386 4 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=1
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x40f795d0> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:401)
at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:102)
at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:73)
at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:168)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"ReferenceQueueDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=5 WAIT
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x418a0d30 self=0x1548890
| sysTid=12094 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=21700000
| schedstat=( 306001 1676076 4 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=1
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x40f794f8> 
at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:364)
at java.lang.Daemons$ReferenceQueueDaemon.run(Daemons.java:128)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"Compiler" daemon prio=5 tid=4 VMWAIT
| group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x418a0c40 self=0x14785b0
| sysTid=12092 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=21838632
| schedstat=( 2274538 10397923 5 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Signal Catcher" daemon prio=5 tid=3 RUNNABLE
| group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x418a0b48 self=0x14b7808
| sysTid=12090 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=21471592
| schedstat=( 4066231 2657077 7 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"GC" daemon prio=5 tid=2 VMWAIT
| group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x418a0a68 self=0x152b8b8
| sysTid=12087 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=21598632
| schedstat=( 1544846 2687077 3 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=1
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

From what I understand this ANR is caused by running long operations on the main UI thread.

My problem is that, as all the methods mentioned in the main thread section of the report are either internal Unity methods or internal Android methods, I have no idea where to start looking for the problem.

Any pointers would be helpful.